# Is there a Unique Identifier anywhere in TVOS I can use?

Tags: tvos, tvos9.1

In developing client/server (TVML/TVJS) I would like to pass a unique identifier to my server as a key to use in a multi-tenet DB.

Is there any identifying information I can access? I checked `UIKit -> UIDevice` but it does not contain any unique property.

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? And why don't down voters add a comment, otherwise it seems subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use the UIDevice's identifierForVendor:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Comment: @Cambell_Souped - I think this may do it. Need to work through the various scenarios but i may be the key I was looking for.